# How to merge a single image with a video file and create a MP4 video file as an output in Android?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, video

anyone know how to merge a **single image** with already selected video  in android through any library because i cannot find any solution for this issue i have checked some libraries such as FFmpeg and OpenCV but they seem not to help in my case 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg can definitely overlay an image over a video if this is what you are looking for.

The documentation provides some some examples - they key option is 'filter-complex':

> ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i image.png -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v]overlay[out]' -map
>   '[out]' out.mkv

See here for the official documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html and look at '-filter_complex filtergraph (global)'

ffmpeg is designed as a command line tool, but there exist 'wrapper' projects to allow it be used from an Android app. A well supported example is below but others exist also:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

The above includes a sample APK so you can try out the ffmpeg command you need with that to ensure it works before adding to your own project.